# Как прочитать XML документ и получить значения (XDocument)

Tags: xml, c#, синтаксический-анализ

Есть XML такого вида:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<items>
 <count>10</count>
   <article>
   <id>318040956</id>
   <name>Название1</name>
   <photo_s>318040956_s.jpg</photo_s>
   <photo_m>318040956_m.jpg</photo_m>
   <photo_l>318040956_l.jpg</photo_l>
   <date>1386612104</date>
  </article>
  <article>
   <id>318095781</id>
   <name>Название2</name>
   <photo_m>318095781_m.jpg</photo_m>
   <photo_l>318095781_l.jpg</photo_l>
   <date>1386686508</date>
  </article>
  <article>
   <id>318344403</id>
   <name>Название3</name>
   <photo_s>318344403_s.jpg</photo_s>
   <photo_m>318344403_m.jpg</photo_m>
   <date>1386964811</date>
  </article>
  </items>
</route>
```

Как можно извлечь значения детей элементов `<article>` отдельно для каждого `<article>`?
Если использовать XPath, то он возвращает массив значений, например, `<date>` сразу для всех `<article>`, пройтись по номерам тоже не вариант, так как `<count>` врет.

Comment: Ничего он не врет, просто наборы детей разные, а потому /article/photo_s[2]/../name/text() вернет то, что вернет, а /article[2]/photo_s/text() вернет и того меньше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Доброго времени суток!

Я бы предложил вам использовать следующий код на основе LINQ for XML. Не самый изящный это уж точно, но своё дело делает :-)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            String xmlString = File.ReadAllText("XMLFile1.xml");
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xmlString));

            var xmlList = (from article in xdoc.Descendants("article")
                select new
                {
                    id = article.Descendants("id").SingleOrDefault(),
                    name = article.Descendants("name").SingleOrDefault(),
                    photo_s = article.Descendants("photo_s").SingleOrDefault(),
                    photo_m = article.Descendants("photo_m").SingleOrDefault(),
                    photo_l = article.Descendants("photo_l").SingleOrDefault(),
                    date = article.Descendants("id").SingleOrDefault()
                }).ToList();

            var articleList = (from item in xmlList
                select new
                {
                    id = item.id != null ? item.id.Value : null,
                    name = item.name != null ? item.name.Value : null,
                    photo_s = item.photo_s != null ? item.photo_s.Value : null,
                    photo_m = item.photo_m != null ? item.photo_m.Value : null,
                    photo_l = item.photo_l != null ? item.photo_l.Value : null,
                    date = item.date != null ? item.date.Value : null
                });

            foreach (var article in articleList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}",
                    article.id, article.date, article.name, article.photo_l, article.photo_m, article.photo_s);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

На входе ваш файлик

[image: кк1]

На выходе данные

[image: кк2]

и обратите внимание что должно быть

```
<root></root>
```

а не

```
<root></route>
```

Надеюсь это вам поможет.

Answer (score 0):

А почему не просто

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(...);
var articles = doc.Root.Elements("items").Single().Elements("article");
```

?

Comment: @VladD Верно, но по сути это строчка №15 моего ответа, а кто дальше парсить будет IEnumerable<XElement> ? :-)

Comment: По сути ваш код не парсит `XElement`. Вы просто перекладываете информацию из одного контейнера в другой.

По сути кроме 15 строчки код вашего ответа бесполезен.

Comment: @VladD да ну? :-)То есть вы пытаетесь меня убедить что код "var id = article.Descendants("id")" не парсит XML выбирая для меня всех элементы id из данной ветки? :-) Хм, да вообще всё программирование это перекладывание информации :-)

Comment: @pvkovalev: разумеется, не парсит. Почитайте про парсинг и подумайте над вопросом о грамматике входящего языка.

Comment: @VladD ну конечно парсит, потому что на основе лексического анализа возвращает мне элементы id. А вы как оказывается не только не можете дать правильный ответ, но и признавать что не правы не умеете :-)

Comment: @pvkovalev: Для начала прочитайте и поймите хотя бы вот это: <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing>. Затем подумайте, что есть лексемами в языке, который ваш код парсит. Затем поймите, почему именно вы не правы.

Comment: @VladD в таком случае у меня нет времени на вас и этот бессмысленный диалог. Если вы захотите, то в вашей же ссылке вы найдёте следующее "A parser is a software component that takes input data (frequently text) and builds a data structure" что при желании позволит вам понять что именно это я и сделал.

Comment: @pvkovalev: Раз вы отвечаете, значит, время есть. Отлично, вы прочитали текст по ссылке. А теперь всё же попробуйте составить грамматику входного языка, и разобраться, что есть ваши лексемы.